# Fresh install in prod? Why?

Tags: deployment, cloud, production

Why do you need to do a fresh install in production than take a snapshot of UAT install it?

We have 3 env. Dev, Staging and Prod. If we have fixed all the issues in Staging, can we take the snapshot and just copy it to production? why is it a  best practice is to recreate the environment with a cloud formation script/ansible script? Why is snapshotting and copying to prod a risk alternative?

Comment: This sounds more like an exam question than a Stack Overflow programming question.

Comment: It is not an exam question,It is real world problem. We are debating how to install our code in Prod. If we bypass using Jenkins and install in prod using a snapshot, we can get to production faster, claims the lead PM. Ops saying thats not clean.. We just want to ensure we wont get into future issues if we did it that way.